# BeautifulSoup4をインストールしているのですが、NameErrorが出て利用できません。

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

PythonでWebスクレイピングを試みていますが、NameErrorが出ます。
BeautifulSoupはインストールされていると思うのですが、記述方法に問題があるのでしょうか。

【環境】
OS：Win7 32bit
Python：3.6.4
IDE：ATOM
環境変数(Pathに追加済み)：`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts`

【パッケージのインストール確認】

```sh
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2017.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.6
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
```

【コード】

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.kyodonews.jp/"
r = requests.get(url)

print(soup.find("h1"))
```

【エラー】

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\code\scraping1.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(soup.find("h1"))
NameError: name 'soup' is not defined
```

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。質問の投稿が初めてだったので、助かりました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーメッセージを読むと、`soup`が定義されていないと書いてありますので、`soup`を定義する必要があります。
`find("h1")`を使おうとしていることから想像すると、`soup`はBeautifulSoupのオブジェクトであるべきです。

要するに、`r`と`BeautifulSoup`を使って、`soup`を作る処理が抜けているということになります。

何か参考にして書かれたのであれば、記述に漏れがないか確認してみてください。

参考までに、動作するように内容を補完するとこうなります：

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.kyodonews.jp/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("h1"))
```

Comment: 補完いただいたとおりに記述したところ、要求どおりに動作しました！
ありがとうございます！

元々参考（というかそのままコピペ）にしたサイトは以下だったのですが、環境やバージョンが異なって動作しなかったのかもしれません。
[スクレイピングをやってみよう ー ゼロから始めるPython入門](http://www.designmap.info/2016/12/05/python-17/)

兎にも角にも、"soupを作る処理"を調べて、正しく理解したいと思います。
ありがとうございました。